# Why is my carousel snapping to the top on user interaction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a carousel on my single page website that displays some of my photography work. The problem I'm having is that whenever I click one of the arrows to access the next picture - left or right, I am instantly snapped to the top of the page!

I've checked through both the CSS and JS and I can't seem to find any reason as to why this would be occurring.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <h3><span class="underline">Exploration</span></h3>
    <p>I love exploring and capturing epic moments on my journeys. Here's some of my favourites from my latest trip across the west coast of America.</p>
</div>    

<div class="slider">

<!--SLIDE 1 START-->

      <div class="slide active-slide slide-feature slide-feature-1">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 

<!--SLIDE 1 END-->

<!--SLIDE 2 START-->

      <div class="slide slide-feature slide-feature-2">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 

<!--SLIDE 2 END-->

<!--SLIDE 3 START-->

      <div class="slide slide-feature slide-feature-3">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 

<!--SLIDE 3 END-->

<!--SLIDE 4 START-->    

      <div class="slide slide-feature slide-feature-4">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 

<!--SLIDE 4 END-->

<!--SLIDE 5 START-->

      <div class="slide slide-feature slide-feature-5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 

<!--SLIDE 5 END-->     

</div>


    <div class="slider-nav">
      <a href="#" class="arrow-prev"><img src="images/arrow-left.svg"></a>
      <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="arrow-next"><img src="images/arrow-right.svg"></a>
    </div>

</div>

<!--FLIPBOARD ENDS HERE-->  

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.exploration {
    height: 1100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.exploration .container {
    position: relative;
    top: 35px;
    width: 1200px;
}

.exploration h3 {
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 40px;  
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.exploration p {
    color: #313131;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}


.slider {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.active-slide {
    display: block;
}

/* Slide feature */

.slide-feature { 
    text-align: center;
    height: 800px;
}

.slide-feature-1 {
  background-image: url('https://scontent-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t31.0-8/11036160_10152854777396270_5157414753497878003_o.jpg');
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-feature-2 {
  background-image: url('https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/t31.0-8/11218515_10152909922431270_7749144937209461633_o.jpg');
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-feature-3 {
  background-image: url('https://scontent-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/11187795_10152891725491270_1769195601160147349_o.jpg');
  background-position: bottom;
}

.slide-feature-4 {
  background-image: url('https://scontent-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t31.0-8/11154672_10152854784061270_3532862830070230799_o.jpg');
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-feature-5 {
  background-image: url('https://scontent-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t31.0-8/11164749_10152909922426270_8192461025609874418_o.jpg');
  background-position: center;  
}

.slide-feature img {
  margin-top: 112px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.arrow-prev {
  margin-right: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}

.arrow-next {
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}

.slider-dots {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}

.slider-dots li {
  color: #bbbcbc;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #7FCCE5;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var main = function() {
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();

});
//Next Arrow Functionality    
$('.arrow-next').click(function() {

    var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide=currentSlide.next();
    var currentDot=$('.active-dot');
    var nextDot=currentDot.next();

    if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
        nextSlide=$('.slide').first();
        nextDot=$('.dot').first();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');

});
//Previous Arrow Click Functionality
$('.arrow-prev').click(function() {

    var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide=currentSlide.prev();

    var currentDot=$('.active-dot');
    var prevDot=currentDot.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length == 0) {
        prevSlide=$('.slide').last(); 
        prevDot=$('.dot').last();
    }


    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');

    });


//Load Jumbotron text on page open.
$("#test h1").addClass("load");

};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parameter (e) to your click callback functions then prevent default post (that an anchor tag with href set has) with this line:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

like this:

```
        //Next Arrow Functionality
        $('.arrow-next').click(function (e) {

            var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
            var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
            var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
            var nextDot = currentDot.next();

            if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
                nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
                nextDot = $('.dot').first();
            }

            currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
            nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

            currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
            nextDot.addClass('active-dot');

            e.preventDefault();
        });
        //Previous Arrow Click Functionality
        $('.arrow-prev').click(function (e) {

            var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
            var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

            var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
            var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

            if (prevSlide.length == 0) {
                prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
                prevDot = $('.dot').last();
            }


            currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
            prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

            currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
            prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I looked into e.preventDefault and got this description: "If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.". By this definition, then, what was the default action causing the issue so I can know for the future?

Comment: The href="#" is causing the page to jump to the top

Comment: @R4nc1d summed it up perfectly, +1 for your fiddle, i got a little lazy :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `e.preventDefault();` to your onlick functions

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxokqrt5/)

***EDIT***
As I just commented in the comment section it is the `href="#"` that is causing the page to the jump to the top. So technically if you remove the achor tag the `e.preventDefault();` is not necessary. But it is good to keep it.